# Return Multiple Objects on STOMP Subscribe Spring Websockets

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

I have a topic `/topic/routes/{routeid}`

Users subscribe to that topic, and get the current location of a bus on that route, using the following controller method:

```
@SubscribeMapping(TOPIC + "/routes/{routeId}")
    public MessageWrapper<BusStatusResponseModel> subscribeToRouteLocation(
            @DestinationVariable(value = "routeId") short routeId) {

            return new MessageWrapper<>(LOCATION_MESSAGE, routeService.getBusForRoute(routeId));

    }
```

However, I would like to try and move my app initialization to websockets instead of REST, so upon subscription, I would like to return multiple seperate messages. For example, the stops on the route, the previous records from this route, etc.

I've tried making the subscription controller method return void, and instead use the SimpMessagingTemplate like so:

```
@SubscribeMapping(TOPIC + "/routes/{routeId}")
public void subscribeToRouteLocation(@DestinationVariable(value = "routeId") short routeId, Principal principal) {
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
                    user.getName(),
                    ROUTES,
                    new MessageWrapper<>(LOCATION_MESSAGE,
                    routeService.getBusForRoute(routeId))
            );
    final LocalDate localDate = dateService.tenantTime().toLocalDate();
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
            user.getName(),
            ROUTES,
            new MessageWrapper<>(
                    MessageWrapper.ROUTE_ACTIVITY_SUBSCRIPTION_MESSAGE,
                    activityService.getAllRouteReportsForRouteInDateRange(routeId, localDate.minusDays(7), localDate))
            );
}
```

However, this sends to /user/... which is not what I want.

Is what I'm asking possible?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `messagingTemplate.convertAndSend()` in stead? Sure, everyone will get the object, but is that a bad thing that other people who subscribe to the same route, will also get the initial messages? Can't they filter those out on the client side? (Or perhaps even use them)

Comment: @g00glen00b I assumed it would be a waste of resources to send when it's unnecessary, is it not that much of a problem to just broadcast when someone subscribes?